# How can I get sessions.el to save my registers?

Tags: session

I am trying to get session to work, and I am especially keen on having my registers persistent between sessions. I installed the package sessions.el via Melpa (M-x list-packages) and I added this to my .emacs

```
(require 'session)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize)
```

and I also added this as recommended in the session.el file (even though desktop is not enabled)

```
(setq desktop-globals-to-save '(desktop-missing-file-warning))
```

This doesn't seem to be working though. I tried saving my registers but they are not persistent across sessions. I tried changing the value of `session-globals-include` via M-x customize-group RET session RET to include register. This is what emacs added to my .emacs file after the changes in custom

```
 '(session-globals-include
   (quote
    ((kill-ring 10 nil)
     (session-file-alist 100 t)
     (file-name-history 200 nil)
     search-ring regexp-search-ring
     (register-alist 100 t))))
 '(session-use-package t nil (session)))
```

Still, when I try to invoke a register using C-x r j r (the set register from the previous session), it says "Register doesn't contain a buffer position or configuration". I am not even sure anything is being saved between sessions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Emacs's built-in desktop.el works out-of-box, simply put `(desktop-save-mode)` to your init.el or .emacs, the package is also documented in Emacs manual (`(info "(emacs) Saving Emacs Sessions")`).

Comment: @xuchunyang OK, I will try that. I found out about desktop after having already wasted 2 hours trying to get sessions to work, so I didn't want it to be for nothing... BTW, should it be (desktop-save-mode 1)?

Comment: `(desktop-save-mode)` is the same as `(desktop-save-mode 1)` for relatively new Emacs version (24?) according to its docstring "If called from Lisp, enable the mode if ARG
is omitted or nil.", you can read its docstring with `C-h f` to make sure that,

Comment: @xuchunyang OK, makes sense. When I was typing desktop-save-mode my minibuffer displayed the name of the function followed by "optional arg" so of course you are right. Desktop worked by the way, thank you :)

Comment: @xuchunyang would you post this as an answer so this doesn't show as a  question with no answers? Vivi, would you then accept this to show this has been addressed?

Comment: @rocky I have posted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Emacs's built-in package `desktop.el` instead, it saves registers by default. To use it, put following to your init file:

```el
(desktop-save-mode)
;; prior to Emacs 24
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

---

You can also use other packages, such as built-in package `savehist.el`, as long as you can use it to keep value of the variable `register-alist` across session.

Comment: deskopt-save-mode incorrect work with multiple  monitors - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68478/does-desktop-save-mode-work-for-multiple-monitors

Comment: you cant use savehist to store register-alist

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```
;; don't use desktop mode for terminal
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (desktop-save-mode 1);; is x window
  ())

;; Add variables to desktop saving
(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'register-alist)
```